# Android - Unable to merge dex on adding Glide library

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting below exception after adding Glide library. Any solution for this?
(I tried cleaning & rebuilding the project)

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge
>   dex

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myyoutubeapp.myyoutubeapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
    //implementation 'com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview:library:0.7.3'
}
```

Comment: clean and rebuild

Comment: @ALTegani already tried

Comment: I got the same problem. @akkk Did you get any solution?